# Specify custom Date format for colClasses argument in read.table/read.csv

Tags: r, date, read.table, read.csv

### Question:

**Is there a way to specify the Date format when using the colClasses argument in read.table/read.csv?**

(I realise I can convert after importing, but with many date columns like this, it would be easier to do it in the import step)

---

### Example:

I have a .csv with date columns in the format `%d/%m/%Y`.

```
dataImport <- read.csv("data.csv", colClasses = c("factor","factor","Date"))
```

This gets the conversion wrong. For example, `15/07/2008` becomes `0015-07-20`.

---

### Reproducible code:

```
data <- 
structure(list(func_loc = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("3076WAG0003", "3076WAG0004", "3076WAG0007", 
"3076WAG0009", "3076WAG0010"), class = "factor"), order_type = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("PM01", "PM02", 
"PM03"), class = "factor"), actual_finish = structure(c(4L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("", "11/03/2008", 
"14/08/2008", "15/07/2008", "17/03/2008", "19/01/2009", "22/09/2008", 
"6/09/2007"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("func_loc", "order_type", 
"actual_finish"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")


write.csv(data,"data.csv", row.names = F)                                                        

dataImport <- read.csv("data.csv")
str(dataImport)
dataImport

dataImport <- read.csv("data.csv", colClasses = c("factor","factor","Date"))
str(dataImport)
dataImport
```

And here's what the output looks like:

[image: code output]

Comment: A hackish way to do this would be to create your own version of `read.table` and add a `format` argument that is passed on to `as.Date`. I wouldn't be surprised if there's a better way that I'm not thinking of, though.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You can write your own function that accepts a string and converts it to a Date using the format you want, then use the `setAs` to set it as an `as` method.  Then you can use your function as part of the colClasses.

Try:

```
setAs("character","myDate", function(from) as.Date(from, format="%d/%m/%Y") )

tmp <- c("1, 15/08/2008", "2, 23/05/2010")
con <- textConnection(tmp)

tmp2 <- read.csv(con, colClasses=c('numeric','myDate'), header=FALSE)
str(tmp2)
```

Then modify if needed to work for your data.

Edit ---

You might want to run `setClass('myDate')` first to avoid the warning (you can ignore the warning, but it can get annoying if you do this a lot and this is a simple call that gets rid of it).

Comment: Note that you might get a 'no definition for class "myDate"' warning as detailed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146341/using-setas-to-specify-colclasses-in-r).

Comment: What is `setMethod('myDate')` supposed to do? Running it just gives me an error...

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, sorry that should have been `setClass` (fixed now).  What it does is prevent `setAs` from issuing a warning about 'myDate' not existing as a class.  The warning is harmless and everything still works, but setting the class means that you don't even see the warning.

Comment: Is it better to just save it as character and then do the conversion of the column to date, or do it as mentioned above?

Comment: @MySchizoBuddy,  If you only have one date column and you are doing this one time then it probably does not matter which way you do it.  But if you have several columns in your dataset that are dates, then I think this approach would probably be simpler than changing each of the columns after reading.

Comment: For those like me who came this thread hoping to implement it within `data.table::fread`, `fread` doesn't implement date types in it's conversions so this will still not work at time of this writing in `fread`.

Answer (score 25):

If there is only 1 date format you want to change, you could use the `Defaults` package to change the default format within `as.Date.character`

```
library(Defaults)
setDefaults('as.Date.character', format = '%d/%M/%Y')
dataImport <- read.csv("data.csv", colClasses = c("factor","factor","Date"))
str(dataImport)
## 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ func_loc     : Factor w/ 5 levels "3076WAG0003",..: 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 5
##  $ order_type   : Factor w/ 3 levels "PM01","PM02",..: 3 3 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 1
##  $ actual_finish: Date, format: "2008-10-15" "2009-10-19" NA "2008-10-11" ...
```

I think @Greg Snow's answer is far better, as it does not change the default behaviour of an often used function.

Answer (score 8):

In case you need time also:

```
setClass('yyyymmdd-hhmmss')
setAs("character","yyyymmdd-hhmmss", function(from) as.POSIXct(from, format="%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
d <- read.table(colClasses="yyyymmdd-hhmmss", text="20150711-130153")
str(d)
## 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
## $ V1: POSIXct, format: "2015-07-11 13:01:53"
```

Answer (score 2):

A long time ago, in the meantime the problem has been solved by Hadley Wickham. So nowadays the solution is reduced to a oneliner:

```
library(readr)
data <- read_csv("data.csv", 
                  col_types = cols(actual_finish = col_datetime(format = "%d/%m/%Y")))
```

Maybe we want even to get rid of unnecessary stuff:

```
data <- as.data.frame(data)
```