# Getting warning using setAs() to specify colClasses in R

Tags: r, class, datetime, warnings, user-defined-types

I tried using the answer @Greg Snow provided in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022299/specify-date-format-for-colclasses-argument-in-read-table-read-csv), but I keep getting a warning regardless of what I do. Can someone help with this:?

```
> setAs("character","myDate",function(from) as.Date(from, format="%b %d, %Y %r"))
in method for ‘coerce’ with signature ‘"character","myDate"’: no definition for class “myDate”
```

I wanted to make sure that the "methods" package is load (it looks like setAs depends on it) and I got this:

```
> getOption("defaultPackages")
[1] "datasets"  "utils"     "grDevices" "graphics"  "stats"     "methods"
```

TIA

Comment: You haven't used setClass yet. (I think it's only a warning but am guessing here since I do not think you provided a complete transcript.)

Comment: Try `setClass("myDate")` before hand

Comment: As you will see if you run that code, it succeeds despite the warning. (And you did provide the complete output.)

Comment: well - color me fancy. It works both with and without using setClass. Stupid me took that as an error and not a warning (would have been nice if it said either way). Thanks guys.