# R shiny reactive data subset

Tags: r, shiny

With the help of fantastic people here at Stackoverflow I've managed to build a shiny web app (thanks to shiny server developers) that lets me select the dataset to use and plots a nice table showing the complete dataset. Now I want the user to input a date range then to show the table for the data only in the range by pressing a submit button.

When the request is submitted an error message appears:

> DataTables warning (table id = 'DataTables_Table_0'): DataTables
>   warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by
>   a JSON formatting error.

I think this is not an R error. I've found some info on JSON googleing but it was related to
Javascript, which I dont't know how to manage. I am using Firefox to test the app.

Please find here the code I'm using for **ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  # Título superior
  headerPanel(""),
  # Panel lateral izquierdo - selección de datos
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("torre", "Torre:",
                list("Place 1" = "place1",
                     "Place 2" = "place2")),       
    selectInput("tipo", "Intervalo de datos",
                list("Daily" = "-daily.csv",
                     "Monthly" = "-monthly.csv")),
    textInput("date1", "Fecha inicial:", "2000-01-01"),
    textInput("date2", "Fecha final:", "2000-01-01"),
    submitButton("Update View")
  ),

  # Panel principal (presentación de gráficas)
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Inicio",
               h3("Consulta de datos"),
               p(HTML("En el panel <i>Ayuda</i> se describen las variables 
                     presentadas en la tabla de datos.")),
               tableOutput("view")
               ),
      tabPanel("Ayuda", htmlOutput("ayuda"),id="ayuda"),
      tabPanel('Tabla de datos', dataTableOutput("mytable3"))      
    )
  )
))
```

and **server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)

options(shiny.transcode.json = FALSE)

# Funciones
shinyServer(function(input,output){

  filename=reactive({
    paste0(input$torre,input$tipo)
    })
  day1=reactive({
    paste0(input$date1," 00:00:00")
  })
  day2=reactive({
    paste0(input$date2," 23:50:00")
  })
  # Lectura de datos  
    datos2=reactive({
    read.csv(filename(),header=T, sep=",",na.strings="-99.9")
  })
  datos=reactive({
    d1 <- as.POSIXct(day1())
    d2 <- as.POSIXct(day2())
    with( datos2() , datos2()[ date >= d1 & date <= d2, ] )
  })
  #  Tabla de datos
  output$mytable3 = renderDataTable({
    datos()
  }, options = list(aLengthMenu = c(10, 25, 50), iDisplayLength = 10))
})
```

Thanks for your help

**EDIT1**

Also tried this piece of code in server.R

```
  datos=reactive(function(){
    subset(datos2(),datos2()$date >= day1())
    subset(datos2(),datos2()$date <= day2())
  })
```

and some variation like

```
  datos=reactive(function(){
    subset(datos2(),date >= input$date1)
    subset(datos2(),date <= input$date2)
  })
```

without succes. In both cases data table shows whole dataset, it seems to run after changing input dates but subsetting does not take effect.

EDIT 2

Data reupload since ubuntu one link was broken. Please, check the data for headers and formats as the original data were lost and maybe there were some changes.

You can find data here [monthly](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7p7zo1d3phjt6ka/torre-monthly.csv?dl=0) and [daily](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7p7zo1d3phjt6ka/torre-monthly.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Can you reupload the data set somewhere? the link is now broken

Comment: Hi @hedgedandlevered As I could not find the original data, it was a subset, I reuploaded a new subset of the original data. You should check and edit the header and data. Hope it works, it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the files you uploaded, only `place2-daily.csv` is valid. `place1-daily` has a corrupt header (check with Notepad), and the monthly do not have a `day` column as required by your subset.

So let's fix the filename:

```
  datos2=reactive({
    #fn = filename()
    fn = "place2-daily.csv"
    f = read.csv(fn,header=T, sep=",",na.strings="-99.9")
    f$date = as.Date(f$date)
    f
  })
  datos=reactive({
    d1 <- as.Date(day1())
    d2 <- as.Date(day2())
    datos2a = datos2()
    with( datos2a , datos2a[ date >= d1 & date <= d2, ] )
  })
```

You `date` is read in as a factor, so you have to convert it first. And in the `datos` part, I recommend to assign to a local variable. My rule of thumb is to always assign whenever a () is called more than once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try your suggestion. Yes, I noticed the monthly files after sending. I need to preprocess data before calling in shiny and assign a date column to all data sets.

Comment: Hi @dieter-menne Perfect, it runs fine and it is exactly what I needed.