# Working with reactiveValues and ggplot in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Im using R and shiny to query an SQL database. The user can search and add to a reactive data frame, the output of which is plotted in ggplot. However, I need to change the columns of the reactive data frames to factors for plotting. I can do this directly with ggplot (`aes(factor(...),` ). However, if I add the option of changing the plotted variable using a reactive input, I must use aes_string. If I use aes_string it does not like `aes(factor(...),`. Here is a working example:

Server:

```
# Create example data

set.seed(10)
MeasurementA <- rnorm(1000, 5, 2)
MeasurementB <- rnorm(1000, 5, 2)

Wafer <- rep(c(1:100), each=10)
ID <- rep(c(101:200), each=10)
Batch <- rep(c(1:10), each=100)

dd <- data.frame(Batch, Wafer, ID, MeasurementA, MeasurementB)

# Create local connection (in reality this will be a connection to a host site)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "dd", dd)
query <-  function(...) dbGetQuery(con, ...)

# Create empty data frames to populate

wq = data.frame()
sq = data.frame()

shinyServer(function(input, output){

  # create data frame to store reactive data set from query
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- data.frame()

  # Action button for first query
  d <- eventReactive(input$do, { input$wafer })

  # First stage of reactive query
  a <- reactive({ paste("Select ID from dd where Wafer=",d(), sep="") })

  wq <- reactive({  query( a() ) })

  # Output to confirm query is correct
  output$que <- renderPrint({ a() }) 
  output$pos <- renderPrint( wq()[1,1] )  

  # Action button to add results from query to a data frame
  e <- eventReactive(input$do2, { wq()[1,1] })

  b <- reactive({ paste("select Wafer, Batch, MeasurementA, MeasurementB from dd where ID=",e()," Order by  ID asc ;", sep="") })

  # observe e() so that data is not added until user presses action button  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(e())) {
      sq <- reactive({  query( b() ) })

      # add query to reactive data frame
      values$df <- rbind(isolate(values$df), sq())
    }
  })


# output of results  

  # Without mesurement choice (works)
  output$boxV <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(values$df, aes(factor(Wafer), MeasurementA, fill=factor(Batch))) + geom_boxplot() 
  })
  # With measurement choice (doesnt work)
  #output$boxV <- renderPlot({
    #ggplot(values$df, aes_string(factor('Wafer'), input$char, fill=factor('Batch'))) + geom_boxplot() 
  #})

  })
```

UI:

```
library(markdown)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Generic grapher"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      numericInput("wafer", label = h3("Input wafer ID:"), value = NULL),

      actionButton("do", "Search wafer"),
      actionButton("do2", "Add to data frame"),
      selectInput("char", label="Boxplot choice:",
                  choices = list("A"="MeasurementA", "B"="MeasurementB"),                            
                  selected="Von.fwd")

      ),

      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("que"), 
        verbatimTextOutput("pos"),
        plotOutput("boxV")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Ive added output plot code for both working and non-working (non-working is commented out).

Now, ive read this ([Formatting reactive data.frames in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201070/formatting-reactive-data-frames-in-shiny)) and this ([R shiny modify reactive data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401932/r-shiny-modify-reactive-data-frame?rq=1)) but im confused. Because im using reactiveValues to store data, I use the code values$df to access the data...but what if i I want to turn a column to a factor for purpose of above? this doesnt seem to work:

```
new <- reactive(as.factor(values$df$Wafer))
```

Perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem by changing the data type within the query itself:

```
b <- reactive({ paste("select cast(Wafer as varchar) as Wafer, cast(Batch as varchar) as Batch, MeasurementA, MeasurementB from dd where ID=",e()," Order by  ID asc ;", sep="") })
```

That way I didnt have to mess about afterwards. It works for me but if anyone reading this wants to tell me that its a bad idea, please do. Im new to SQL and R so please correct me so I can learn. Thanks