# Edit data frame after upload with R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, edit, import-from-csv

I built a shiny app which takes a CSV file uploaded by the user and adds headers to it 
and a couple of new columns, in order to do some calculation afterwards.

The uploaded CSV file consists in 2 columns like this:

```
1  0.21
1  0.20
1  0.23
2  0.40
2  0.42
2 ...
```

To upload the file I use this code (which is working):

```
data1<- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if(is.null(inFile)){return()}
    data1<- read.csv(file=inFile$datapath,header =input$header,sep=input$sep)
})
```

Next step would be add the headers to this two columns and add two more columns in this way:

```
Dose  Response SquareRoot    Log  
1     0.21     sq(Response)  log(Response)
1     0.20     ...           ...
1     0.23     ...           ...
2     0.40     ...           ...
2     0.42     ...           ...
2 ...
```

In an R session the code I would use is this:

```
  data1<- read.csv(file=inFile$datapath,header =input$header,sep=input$sep)
  colnames(data1) <-c("Dose","Response")
  data1$ResponseLog <- log10(data1$Response + 1)
  data1$ResponseSqRoot <- sqrt(data1$Response + 1)
```

If I do this in shiny adding these lines into my Rshiny app it won't work and give me the error: 
**ERROR:argument of length 0** even if I just define the column names using `colnames()`.

So my question is, is there a way to edit the dataframe I just uploaded? I this question has already been asked could you redirect me there because I couldn't find the solution.
I hope I gave you enough details to understand the problem.

Comment: Check out this quetion - I think  it may help http://stackoverflow.com/q/20201070/2679518

Comment: So, first I upload the file using `reactiveFileReader()` and then I create a new object which will allow me to modify the dataframe.
Am I right?

Comment: Basically yes, you would make the data.frame with the correct column names. Then you would reactively add the uploaded data to the columns. Then you can do any calculations etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this helps: I added a button to it too

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',accept = c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values','text/tab-separated-values','text/plain','.csv','.tsv')),
      checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
      radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'),'Comma'),
      radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',c(None='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"),'Double Quote'),
      actionButton("Load", "Load the File"),width = 3),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("my_output_data"))
)

server = function(input, output) {

  data1 <- reactive({
    if(input$Load == 0){return()}
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}

    isolate({ 
    input$Load
    my_data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header,sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote,stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
    colnames(my_data) <-c("Dose","Response")
    my_data$ResponseLog <- log10(my_data$Response + 1)
    my_data$ResponseSqRoot <- sqrt(my_data$Response + 1)
    })
    my_data
  })
  output$my_output_data <- renderTable({data1()},include.rownames=FALSE)  

}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Happy to help, please go through the tutorials on the Shiny Main Page