# Converting the datatype of columns in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app.

For this app, I have first created a fileinput() where user can upload the csv file they want and look at the dataset with statistics.

I would like to change the datatype of the columns from factors to numeric inthe displayed dataset and then perform analytics online.

I searched through web to get a starting point for developing this idea, but could not find any.

any lead on how i could select my required variable and change its datatype , would be helpful

here is the code i have tried so far.

UI

```
ui<- shinyUI(

  fluidPage(
  titlePanel("File Input - Upload multiple files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file","Upload the file", multiple = TRUE, accept = c("text/csv", 
                                                                      "text/comma-seperated-values, text/plain",
                                                                      ".csv")), # fileinput() function is used to get the file upload contorl option
      helpText("Default max. file size is 5MB"),
      helpText("Select the read.table parameters below"),
      checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = TRUE),
      checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ','),
      uiOutput("selectfile")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tb")

    )

  )
))
```

SERVER code:

```
server<- shinyServer(function(input,output) {

  ## input$file is a data frame and contains the details around the name, size and temp location of the files uploaded
  # this reactive output display the content of the input$file dataframe
  output$filedf <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(input$file)){return ()}
    input$file # the file input data frame object that contains the file attributes
  })

  # Extract the file path for file
  output$filedf2 <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(input$file)){return ()}
    input$file$datapath # the file input data frame object that contains the file attributes
  })

  ## Below code to display the structure of the input file object
  output$fileob <- renderPrint({
    if(is.null(input$file)){return ()}
    str(input$file)
  })

  ## Side bar select input widget coming through renderUI()
  # Following code displays the select input widget with the list of file loaded by the user
  output$selectfile <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$file)) {return()}
    list(hr(), 
         helpText("Select the files for which you need to see data and summary stats"),
         selectInput("Select", "Select", choices=input$file$name)
    )

  })

  ## Summary Stats code ##
  # this reactive output contains the summary of the dataset and display the summary in table format
  output$summ <- renderPrint({
    if(is.null(input$file)){return()}
    summary(read.csv(file=input$file$datapath[input$file$name==input$Select], 
                       sep=input$sep, 
                       header = input$header, 
                       stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors))})

  ## Dataset code ##
  # This reactive output contains the dataset and display the dataset in table format
  output$table <- renderTable({ 
    if(is.null(input$file)){return()}
    read.csv(file=input$file$datapath[input$file$name==input$Select], sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)

  })

  ## MainPanel tabset renderUI code ##
  # the following renderUI is used to dynamically generate the tabsets when the file is loaded. 
  # Until the file is loaded, app will not show the tabset.
  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$file)) {return()}
    else
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Input File Object DF ", tableOutput("filedf"), tableOutput("filedf2")),
        tabPanel("Input File Object Structure", verbatimTextOutput("fileob")),
        tabPanel("Dataset", tableOutput("table")),
        tabPanel("Summary Stats", verbatimTextOutput("summ")))
  })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Claim Model"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("1"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput('dynamicText')
    )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: did you meant to say that you want another `select` option for selecting columns that needs to be changed to another type?

Comment: @akrun the idea behind selection is that, I have 34 varaibles in my dataset, I want only 15 variable from the dataset. By default they are factor datatype.I want to convert them to numeric for my further analysis.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20201070/2679518

Comment: @JohnPaul it gives me an idea, since i am new to shiny, I am failing how i could integrate the same idea. any piece of code as a start with my code would be helpful