# Most elegant way to load csv with point as thousands separator in R

Tags: r, csv, decimal, decimalformat, decimal-point

**NB:** To the best of my knowledge this question is not a duplicate! All the questios/answers I found are either how to eliminate points from data that are already in R or how to change the decimal point to a comma when loading it.

I have a csv with numbers like: `4.123,98`. The problem is that because of the `.` the output becomes a character string matrix when loading with `read.table`, `read.csv` or `read.csv2`. Changing `dec` to `,` doesn't help.

**My question**
What is the most elegant way to load this csv so that the numbers become e.g. `4123.98` as numeric?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adapted from this post: [Specify custom Date format for colClasses argument in read.table/read.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022299/specify-custom-date-format-for-colclasses-argument-in-read-table-read-csv)

```
#some sample data
write.csv(data.frame(a=c("1.234,56", "1.234,56"),
                     b=c("1.234,56", "1.234,56")),
          "test.csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=TRUE)

#define your own numeric class
setClass('myNum')
#define conversion
setAs("character", "myNum",
      function(from) as.numeric(gsub(",", "\\.", gsub("\\.", "", from))))

#read data with custom colClasses
read_data = read.csv("test.csv",
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                     colClasses=c("myNum", "myNum"))
#let's try whether this is really a numeric
read_data[1, 1] * 2

#[1] 2469.12
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than try to fix it all at loading time, I would load the data into R as a string, then process it to numeric.

So after loading, it's a column of strings like "4.123,98"

Then do something like:

```
 number.string <- gsub("\\.", "", number.string)
 number.string <- gsub(",", "\\.", number.string)
 number <- as.numeric(number.string)
```