# Read csv with numeric columns containing thousands separator

Tags: r, csv

The csv file I'm trying to read has exactly the following format :

```
Date,x,y
"2015/08/01","71,131","20,390"
"2015/08/02","81,599","23,273"
"2015/08/03","79,435","21,654"
"2015/08/04","80,733","20,924"
```

The separator is comma, but each value is also enclosed in quotes because of the comma that serves as a thousands separator. I tried `read.csv` , `read_csv`  from {readr} and `fread`  from {data.table} and the best I can do is read all values is as strings and then use a combination of `as.numeric` and `gsub` to transform them into numbers.

I also found this: [Most elegant way to load csv with point as thousands separator in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218209/most-elegant-way-to-load-csv-with-point-as-thousands-separator-in-r)  It is quite useful, but my data has a lot of columns (not all numeric) and I'd rather not specify column types.

Any ideas or should I start gsub-ing? On the fun side, Excel reads the file just fine :)

Comment: Do you know which columns have to be transformed?

Comment: @Jaap I guess, but at least it will read it correctly. Ah just saw they already tried that. nvm

Comment: David - I'm not sure what that would accomplish. Anyway, I get this error: ` Expected sep (' ') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 4 when detecting types (   first): Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy) `

Comment: Because you need to read it in the correct format, I couldn't format that in comments. Buy I guess you already tried that anyway.

Comment: @Jaap - right now I do know (about 40 columns). However, there will be columns added in the future and I'd rather not perform manual changes each time.

Comment: If Excel can read the file correctly, then you could load it into Excel and resave as a tab-separated value file (might be ".txt" option).  What's wrong with using `as.numeric` though?

Comment: @BogdanC See my answer for a possible solution. How are these future columns added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to read the data with `read.csv`. Here an example

```
#write data
write('Date,x,y\n"2015/08/01","71,131","20,390"\n"2015/08/02","81,599","23,273"\n"2015/08/03","79,435","21,654"\n"2015/08/04","80,733","20,924"',"test.csv")

#use "text" rather than "file" in read.csv
#perform regex substitution before using read.csv
#the outer gsub with '(?<=\\d),(\\d{3})(?!\\d)' performs the thousands separator substitution
#the inner gsub replaces all \" with '
read.csv(text=gsub('(?<=\\d),(\\d{3})(?!\\d)',
                   '\\1',
                   gsub("\\\"",
                        "'",
                        paste0(readLines("test.csv"),collapse="\n")),
                   perl=TRUE),
         header=TRUE,
         quote="'",
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The result

```
#        Date     x     y
#1 2015/08/01 71131 20390
#2 2015/08/02 81599 23273
#3 2015/08/03 79435 21654
#4 2015/08/04 80733 20924
```

Comment: @BogdanC Please check with some sample data. It's hard to say beforehand if a regular expression processes all possible input correctly.

Comment: @cyro - wow! I hadn't given regular expressions a thought at all. I tested on some real data an it works great, I love that I don't have to adjust for column names or types. Thank you!

Comment: @BogdanC Glad it worked! BTW: You could make the regex pattern more restrictive (and therefore probably more fail-safe) by also including the enclosing quotation marks `"`.

Answer (score 3):

With the `data.table` package you could do it as follows:

**1:** Create a vector of columnnames to be transformed. In this case the `Date` has to be excluded.

```
cols <- setdiff(names(dt),"Date")
```

**2:** Apply a transformation function to the remaining columns:

```
library(data.table)
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))), .SDcols = cols]
```

This results in:

```
> dt
         Date     x     y
1: 2015/08/01 71131 20390
2: 2015/08/02 81599 23273
3: 2015/08/03 79435 21654
4: 2015/08/04 80733 20924
```

---

Used data:

```
dt <- fread('Date,x,y
            "2015/08/01","71,131","20,390"
            "2015/08/02","81,599","23,273"
            "2015/08/03","79,435","21,654"
            "2015/08/04","80,733","20,924"')
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to remove all this formatting from your Excel sheet before exporting it.

Failing that, just use `lapply` to convert each column:

```
df[c("x", "y")] <- lapply(df[c("x", "y")], function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x)))
```