# Read in numbers from csv file with point as thousands separator

Tags: r, csv

I want to read in a csv file with numbers such as `123.456` where the `.` is a thousands separator. However, R treats the `.` as a decimal separator and instead of `123456` it gives me `123.456`. Is there an easier solution than the ones outlined in [R - read csv with numeric columns containing thousands separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970770/r-read-csv-with-numeric-columns-containing-thousands-separator)?

```
write("123.456", "number.csv")
read.csv("number.csv", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: maybe use `x$V1 = as.numeric(gsub('\\.','',x$V1))`. If your data also have another character that acts as a decimal separator (perhpas a comma?) then you would also need to change those

Comment: The `read.csv2`  variant used in countries that use a comma as decimal point and a semicolon as field separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The world is full of crazy people from crazy places who write numbers in crazy ways. In computing all this craziness is called "locale".

The `readr` package allows you to specify locale options. You are interested in what is variously called the "grouping mark" or "thousands separator".

For example:

```
library(readr)
read_csv('x,y\n1.234,5.678') # Default is not what you want
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1.23  5.68

# This is what you want
read_csv('x,y\n1.234,5.678', locale = locale(grouping_mark = "."))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1234  5678
```