# R: How can I read a CSV file with data.table::fread, that has a comma as decimal and point as thousand separator="."

Tags: r, data.table, fread, read.csv, readr

I got several CSV files which contain numbers in the local german style i.e. with a comma as the decimal separator and the point as the thousand separator e.g. 10.380,45. The values in the CSV file are separated by ";". The files also contain columns from the classes character, Date, Date & Time and Logical.

The problem with the read.table functions is, that you can specify the decimal separator with dec=",", but NOT the thousand point separator. (If I'm wrong, please correct me)

I know that preprocessing is a workaround, but I want to write my code in a way, that others can use it without me.

I found a way to read the CSV file the way I want it with read.csv2, by setting my own classes, as can be seen in the following example. 
Based on [Most elegant way to load csv with point as thousands separator in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218209/most-elegant-way-to-load-csv-with-point-as-thousands-separator-in-r)

```
# Create test example
df_test_write <- cbind.data.frame(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j",rep("k",times=200)),
                            c("5.200,39","250,36","1.000.258,25","3,58","5,55","10.550,00","10.333,00","80,33","20.500.000,00","10,00",rep("3.133,33",times=200)),
                            c("25.03.2015","28.04.2015","03.05.2016","08.08.2016","08.08.2016","08.08.2016","08.08.2016","08.08.2016","08.08.2016","08.08.2016",rep("08.08.2016",times=200)),
                            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(df_test_write) <- c("col_text","col_num","col_date")

# write test csv
write.csv2(df_test_write,file="Test.csv",quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)

#### read with read.csv2 ####

# First, define your own class

#define your own numeric class
setClass('myNum')
#define conversion
setAs("character","myNum", function(from) as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",gsub("\\.","",from))))

# own date class
library(lubridate)
setClass('myDate')
setAs("character","myDate",function(from) dmy(from))

# Read the csv file, in colClasses the columns class can be defined
df_test_readcsv <- read.csv2(paste0(getwd(),"/Test.csv"),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                       colClasses = c(
                         col_text = "character",
                         col_num = "myNum",
                         col_date = "myDate"
                       )
                )
```

My problem now is, that the different datasets have up to 200 columns and 350000 Rows. With the upper solution I need between 40 and 60 seconds to load one CSV file and I would like to speed this up.

Through my research I found `fread()` from the `data.table` package, which is really fast. It takes approximately 3 to 5 seconds to load the CSV file.

Unfortunately there is also no possibility to specify the thousand separator. So I tried to use my solution with colClasses, but there seems to be the issue, that you can't use individual classes with fread https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/491

See also my following test code:

```
##### read with fread ####
library(data.table)

# Test without colclasses
df_test_readfread1 <- fread(paste0(getwd(),"/Test.csv"),
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                            dec = ",",
                            sep=";",
                            verbose=TRUE)
str(df_test_readfread1)

# PROBLEM: In my real dataset it turns the number into an numeric column, 
# unforunately it sees the "." as decimal separator, so it turns e.g. 10.550, 
# into 10.5
# Here it keeps everything as character

# Test with colclasses
df_test_readfread2 <- fread(paste0(getwd(),"/Test.csv"),
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                            colClasses = c(
                              col_text = "character",
                              col_num = "myNum",
                              col_date = "myDate"
                            ),
                            sep=";",
                            verbose=TRUE)
str(df_test_readfread2)

# Keeps everything as character
```

So my question is: Is there a way to read CSV files with numeric values like 10.380,45 with fread?

(Alternatively: What is the fastest way to read a CSV with such numeric values?)

Comment: See [#1636](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1636). This strikes me as a deficiency... not sure why setting `options("datatable.fread.dec.locale" = "de_DE.utf8")` doesn't fix the problem. @Arun is that not odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used package myself, but it's from Hadley Wickham, should be good stuff

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/readr.pdf

It supposed to handle locales:

`locale(date_names = "en", date_format = "%AD", time_format = "%AT",
decimal_mark = ".", grouping_mark = ",", tz = "UTC",
encoding = "UTF-8", asciify = FALSE)`

`decimal_mark` and `grouping_mark` is what you're looking for

EDIT form PhiSeu: Solution

Thanks to your suggestion here are two solutions with `read_csv2()` from the `readr` package. For my 350000 row CSV file it takes approximately 8 seconds, which is much faster then the read.csv2 solution. 
(Another helpful package from hadley and RStudio, thanks)

```
library(readr)

# solution 1 with specified columns
df_test_readr <- read_csv2(paste0(getwd(),"/Test.csv"),
                           locale = locale("de"),
                           col_names = TRUE,
                           cols(
                             col_text = col_character(),
                             col_num = col_number(), # number is automatically regcognized through locale=("de")
                             col_date2 = col_date(format ="%d.%m.%Y") # Date specification
                           )
                           )

# solution 2 with overall definition of date format
df_test_readr <- read_csv2(paste0(getwd(),"/Test.csv"),
                           locale = locale("de",date_format = "%d.%m.%Y"), # specifies the date format for the whole file
                           col_names = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove all commas first maybe.

```
filepath<-paste0(getwd(),"/Test.csv")
filestring<-readChar(filepath, file.info(filepath)$size)
filestring<-gsub('.','',filestring,fixed=TRUE)
fread(filestring)
```

Comment: This doesn't help unfortunately. fread detects this automatically (if you look at the printed code when verbose=TRUE). I added it to the example, to make it clear. But thanks.

Comment: @PhiSeu sorry I tested it on my machine and it complained about machine locales so didn't know if it would work for you.

Comment: No problem. You might have a problem in the example with the working directory where the CSV file will be wrote and read. I tested my example in the context of a RProject (on Windows 7). So it might not work for everybody.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, unfortunately that deletes the dec "," separator, so 3.133,33 becomes 3.133,33. If I change your solution to filestring<-gsub('.','',filestring,fixed=TRUE) it deletes the points in my date column.

Comment: @PhiSeu oh yeah I meant for it to be "." not "," but I'm too used to US way.  You shouldn't need points in your date column.  I would use `colClasses` to make it a  string when loading and then modify if after loading with `as.POSIXct(colname, format="%Y%m%d")`.  Obviously you'll have to change format to match exactly what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Found this discussion while working on the same problem. I ended up with

```
    dat <- fread(
        "myfile.csv", dec=",", sep=";", encoding="UTF-8"
    ) |> suppressWarnings()

    for (cn in numcols) if(!is.numeric(dat[,.(cn)])) {
        set(dat, j=cn, value=gsub(".", "", dat[[cn]], fixed=TRUE))
        set(dat, j=cn, value=gsub(",", ".", dat[[cn]], fixed=TRUE))
        set(dat, j=cn, value=as.numeric(dat[[cn]]))
    }
```

where `numcols` is a character vector of the names of the columns that are expected to be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Yout can plug-in the custom type in `data.table::fread` like so, with the help of the `readr::locale`:

```
    library(data.table)
    library(readr)

    setAs("character","myDate",function(from) lubridate::dmy(from))
    # define your own numeric class
    setClass('myNumeric')
    # define conversion from character to myNumeric
    setAs("character", "myNumeric", \(from) 
      parse_number(from, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",", 
                                         grouping_mark = ".")))
    dat <- fread("myfile.csv", 
                  dec=",", 
                  sep=";", 
                  encoding="UTF-8";
                  colClasses = c(col_text = "character",
                                 col_num = "myNumeric",
                                 col_date = "myDate")
```

What is being leveraged here is the `colClasses` specification which relies on the custom class conversion definition by `setAs`.