# R read csv with a custom factor

Tags: r

Is it possible to read csv files in R and specify the factor levels?

Suppose I have the following csv:

```
factor1,factor2
0,1
1,0
```

with the following factor:

```
factor(c('dead', 'alive'))
```

`colClasses` doesn't really work as it names the levels 0 and 1 instead of a custom factor.

Comment: You dould do a custom class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022299/specify-date-format-for-colclasses-argument-in-read-table-read-csv

Comment: @user20650 But how would that perform from a memory consumption point of view?

Comment: Why don't you just fix the factor after reading the csv file?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen; I have no idea ..  Ive always been quite happy defining factor levels in my script after reading in the data

Comment: @Pascal If there's no easy way I'll just stick to that.

Comment: I guess it is the easiest (and safest?) way.