# Reading dates with a period as a separator

Tags: r, readr

Having problems reading a European date format of date.month.year in R using readr, where date and month do not have leading zeros. 
E.g.

file:

```
1 date_of_birth
2 1.2.2016
```

Tried (among others):

```
file <- read_csv2("file.csv",col_types = cols(
  date_of_birth=col_date("%d.%m.%Y")
  ))
```

results in
date_of_birth : num 122016

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You would probably benefits from defining your own date format before calling read.csv2.  See this post:  [Specify custom Date format for colClasses argument in read.table/read.csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022299/specify-custom-date-format-for-colclasses-argument-in-read-table-read-csv).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
> as.Date(gsub("\\.","\\/","1.2.2016"),"%d/%m/%Y")
```

[1] "2016-02-01"

Comment: `as.Date("1.2.2016","%d.%m.%Y")` should also work.

Comment: Thanks. This would work when the date variable would already be in that format in R. But when reading a csv file using readr::read_csv the variable is converted to a number and the periods are stripped (eg. "122016"). As there are no leading zeros this is difficult to convert to a date. So need to instruct read_csv to recognize the variable in the csv file as a date, which I cannot do.

Comment: try data.table::fread and then colClass= 'character' and go from there

Comment: Thanks Carl, that was a simple solution. Using readr:
file <- read_csv2("file.csv",col_types = cols(
  Date_of_birth=col_character()
  ))
file$Date_of_birth <- as.Date(file$Date_of_birth, "%d.%m.%Y")

Comment: so it worked for you?

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks!

Comment: so...this is awkward... but you wanna check that accepted option?

Comment: I took your advise on reading the date as a string and the parsed that to a date. Just used dplyr::readr and read_csv instead of data.table::fread.

Comment: okay so this answer is not accepted?