# Can read_csv parse m/d/Y H:M:S AM/PM vector?

Tags: r, datetime, tidyverse

I'm working through learning tidyverse principles and was wondering if there was an easier/better way to bring in my data that includes a datetime vector in a m/d/Y H:M:S AM/PM format. Currently I import with `read_csv`, which recognizes the column in character format, and then I use ludridate to create a new column using `mdy_hms` to parse the datetime column:

```
> test <- read_csv("data.csv")
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  ActivityMinute = col_character(),
  Steps = col_integer()
)
> head(test)         
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     ActivityMinute Steps
              <chr> <int>
1 5/12/2016 12:00:00 AM     0
2 5/12/2016 12:01:00 AM     0
3 5/12/2016 12:02:00 AM     0
4 5/12/2016 12:03:00 AM     0
5 5/12/2016 12:04:00 AM     0
6 5/12/2016 12:05:00 AM     0

> test$datetime <- mdy_hms(test$ActivityMinute)
> head(test)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ActivityMinute Steps            datetime
              <chr> <int>              <dttm>
1 5/12/2016 12:00:00 AM     0 2016-05-12 00:00:00
2 5/12/2016 12:01:00 AM     0 2016-05-12 00:01:00
3 5/12/2016 12:02:00 AM     0 2016-05-12 00:02:00
4 5/12/2016 12:03:00 AM     0 2016-05-12 00:03:00
5 5/12/2016 12:04:00 AM     0 2016-05-12 00:04:00
6 5/12/2016 12:05:00 AM     0 2016-05-12 00:05:00
```

Is there a better way to do this, perhaps using cols()? I tried specifying the `ActivityMinute` as `col_datetime`, but that didn't work. Any tips for better code/process are appreciated.

Comment: `read.table` has an option for `colClasses`.

Comment: @R.Schifini - admittedly it takes a bit more work when you have to sepcify a class conversion function like https://stackoverflow.com/a/13022441/496803

Comment: @thelatemail - yes, as I mentioned in the comment below, I tried this but the times weren't parsed correctly. I guess I was wondering if there was a more simplistic way to pass lubridate functions into the import step.

Comment: Just to note that RStudio makes this process a little easier: use "Import Dataset", then you can interactively choose the column type and experiment with the format until it looks right. And then the code is generated and can be saved for next time.

Comment: @neilfws thanks for this tip. I just tested with @Sraffa's solution below (with `%I` instead of `%H` and it worked great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the datetime format in the `col_datetime` call:

```
test <- 
 read_csv(
  "data.csv", 
   col_types = cols(
    ActivityMinute = col_datetime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), 
    Steps = col_integer()
   )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I should have put that I tried using the `col_datetime`, but it parses it incorrectly. I end up with 12 midnight turning into 12:00:00 rather than 00:00:00 and NAs for the noon hour....

Comment: It works on my computer. Did you set the format argument correctly (`"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"`)?

Comment: With 12-hour times, you need `%I:%M:%S %p`, not `%H`, which is 24-hour.

Comment: Nice! thank you @Sraffa and @alistaire for the tip on using `%I` and not `%H`.