# Shiny error 'comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types' when filtering a reactive variable by date

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use dateRangeInput to filter and summarise some data. I'm getting the following error:

`Warning: Error in >=.default: comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types`

My code :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)


dat <- reactiveFileReader(
  intervalMillis = 100000,  
  NULL,
  filePath = 'appData/data.csv',
  readFunc = read.csv,
  header = TRUE
)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "figures")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(uiOutput('sidebar'))
body <- dashboardBody(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),uiOutput("body"))

fluidRow1 <- fluidRow(
  infoBoxOutput("calls")
)

ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'figures', header, sidebar, body, skin='blue')

server <- function(input, output, session){

  overall <- reactive({
    dat() %>%
      filter(date >= input$dates[1]) %>%
      filter(date <= input$dates[2]) %>%
      select(-date) %>%
      summarise_all(.funs = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
  })


output$body <- renderUI({
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = 'overall', class = 'active', h2(fluidRow1))
  )})

output$sidebar <- renderUI({
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Overall", tabName = "overall", icon = icon("adjust"),
             menuSubItem(icon = NULL,
                         dateRangeInput(inputId = 'dates', 
                                        label = 'Range:', 
                                        start = '2019-10-03', 
                                        end = '2019-10-10'
                         ))
             ))
})

output$calls <- renderInfoBox({
  infoBox(
    "Total Calls", overall()[1,1], icon = icon("list"),
    color = "purple"
  )
})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My data looks like this:

```
         date recordsCreated optionsCreated
1  2019-03-08             NA             NA
2  2019-03-08             NA             NA
3  2019-03-08             NA              1
4  2019-03-08             NA             NA
5  2019-03-08             NA             NA
6  2019-03-08              5              2
7  2019-03-08              8              6
8  2019-03-08             NA             NA
9  2019-03-08              4              3
10 2019-03-08             NA             NA
```

So it looks like the date column is actually a factor, so i tried to change it to an actual date by changing the filter to

```
overall <- reactive({
    dat() %>%
      filter(as.Date(date) >= input$dates[1]) %>%
      filter(as.Date(date) <= input$dates[2]) %>%
      select(-date) %>%
      summarise_all(.funs = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
  })
```

Which gives the error

`Warning: Error in as.Date.default: do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date”`

Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem with [`as.Date`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/as.Date) is that you are not specifying the format. Try this out:

```
as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

But I think it would be best to format the dates at `reactiveFileReader` by setting `colClasses` parameter of the `read.csv` function. Using [`setAs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022299/specify-custom-date-format-for-colclasses-argument-in-read-table-read-csv) you can create a method to this specific date format:

```
setAs("character","myDate", function(from) as.Date(from, format="%Y-%m-%d") )

dat <- reactiveFileReader(
  intervalMillis = 100000,  
  NULL,
  filePath = 'appData/data.csv',
  readFunc = read.csv,
  colClasses=c('myDate','numeric','numeric'),
  header = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably left this problem a long time ago, but it looks like you need an extra set of parentheses inside the reactive.

`object <- reactive ({  (reactive_content) })`

That seems to be fixing my issue.